# Is it possible for a function to change the size of a slice of string array declared elsewhere? golang

Tags: arrays, go, pass-by-reference, slice

I would like to remove an element from the slice in place. But when I do this I end up producing two empty elements in the underlying array.
I already searched [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks), [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

```
package main

import "fmt"

//String remove adjacent duplicates from a string array
func rmDup(str []string) []string {
    for i := 1; i < len(str); i++ {
        if str[i] == str[i-1] {
            copy(str[i:], str[i+1:])
            str[len(str)-1] = ""
            str = str[:len(str)-1]
        }
    }
    return str
}

func main() {

    str := []string{"dog", "cat", "cat", "mouse", "mouse", "zebra", "zebra"}

    fmt.Println(str)
    newstr := rmDup(str)
    fmt.Println(str)
    fmt.Println(newstr)
    fmt.Println(len(str), cap(str), "final")
    fmt.Println(len(newstr), cap(newstr), "final")
}
```

Is there any way that **str** in main can return the **size** and **capacity** defined in rmDup()

Comment: If you want to modify a value, you need a pointer to that value, not a copy.

Comment: It worked almost de same way as the length and capacity of the slice changed but i still can't get rid of the blank spaces at the end of the array. https://play.golang.org/p/2zVBE7ZT-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I was able to find the answer myself. Since the Go language performs function calls by value it is impossible to change a slice declared in another scope, except using pointers.

```
package main

import "fmt"

//String remove adjacent duplicates from a string array
func rmDup(str *[]string) []string {
 var s = *str
 for i := 1; i < len(s); i++ {
    if s[i] == s[i-1] {
        copy(s[i:], s[i+1:])
        s[len(s)-1] = ""
        s = s[:len(s)-1]
    }
}
*str = s
return s
}

func main() {

  str := []string{"dog", "cat", "cat", "mouse", "mouse", "zebra", 
  "zebra"}

  fmt.Println(str)
  newstr := rmDup(&str)
  fmt.Println(str)
  fmt.Println(newstr)
  fmt.Println(len(str), cap(str), "final")
  fmt.Println(len(newstr), cap(newstr), "final")
}
```

Output:

```
[dog cat cat mouse mouse zebra zebra]
[dog cat mouse zebra]
[dog cat mouse zebra]
4 7 final
4 7 final
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way that `str` in `main` can return the size and capacity
>   defined in `rmDup()`?

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

//String remove adjacent duplicates from a string array
func rmDup(str []string) []string {
    for i := 1; i < len(str); i++ {
        if str[i] == str[i-1] {
            copy(str[i:], str[i+1:])
            str[len(str)-1] = ""
            str = str[:len(str)-1]
        }
    }
    return str
}

func main() {
    str := []string{"dog", "cat", "cat", "mouse", "mouse", "zebra", "zebra"}
    fmt.Println(len(str), cap(str), str)
    str = rmDup(str)
    fmt.Println(len(str), cap(str), str)
}
```

Output:

```
7 7 [dog cat cat mouse mouse zebra zebra]
4 7 [dog cat mouse zebra]
```

> i meant in place without the function `rmDup()` having to return
>   anything.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

//String remove adjacent duplicates from a string array
func rmDup(str *[]string) {
    s := *str
    for i := 1; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == s[i-1] {
            copy(s[i:], s[i+1:])
            s[len(s)-1] = ""
            s = s[:len(s)-1]
        }
    }
    *str = s
}

func main() {
    str := []string{"dog", "cat", "cat", "mouse", "mouse", "zebra", "zebra"}
    fmt.Println(len(str), cap(str), str)
    rmDup(&str)
    fmt.Println(len(str), cap(str), str)
}
```

Output:

```
7 7 [dog cat cat mouse mouse zebra zebra]
4 7 [dog cat mouse zebra]
```

Comment: i meant in place without the function rmDup() having to return anything